# SSAS Cube Semi Aditive measure LastChild Across Time but MAX across Few Others and Sum Accross Portfolio

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I have a SQL SERVER 2008R2 Standard Edition. The Cube has one measure called "AUM". Basically this measure is only additive across One Dimension Portfolio.

Across Time I need to pick LastChild, Across Security I need to pick Max and Across Portfolio I need to pick SUM.

How should I create the measure ? what should be the Aggregation property to achieve all 3 types of calculations.

currently we have written SCOPE statement for Security and Time to overwrite Default SUM behavior. this works great but as the members in security and Time Dimension increases the SSRS reporting query gets slow down a lot.

I am currently testing creating new persisted measures with changing the property of aggregations and combinations of some additional create member statements to see if I can avoid scope statements.

Any kind of help be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice problem. some thoughts

There is a problem on the order you evalute your tuple if the aggregation is not associative. I'd take care with scope (when you're evaluating a tuple that does not fall inside). Check this [presentation](http://www.sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event8/Fun_with_Scoped_Assignments_in_MDX) from [Chris Webb](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/) (nice SSAS guru)

The order of you aggregation is important, LastChild(Max(Sum( tuple) ) ) is not Max( LasChild (Sum (tuple) ) ). I'd go for a calculated member if performance is a problem :

First calculating the LastChild with data in your time dimension. Here you can use any aggregation method with a nonempty. Once you got using another measure to get properly the max.

P.S. : I think in SSAS you can define special aggregation methods (somewhere there is an use case for that).

hope it helps